# How do I use Functions inside a Matrix/Table?

Tags: functions, list-manipulation

How do I plug in numerical values to functions that are inside tables and matrices? I've tried making a function that contains a matrix of functions.

```
V[x_] := {{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {Sec[x], Csc[x]}};
V[[1, 1]][5]
```

Produces

```
Sin[x][5]
```

Instead of Sin[5]

Comment: Crossposted Here: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2479834

Comment: try `V[5][[1, 1]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression

```
V[x_] := {{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {Sec[x], Csc[x]}}
```

already sets you up for "plug[ging] in". All you need to do is this:

```
V[5]
```

If you then want just the Sin expression, then you can use Part:

```
V[5][[1, 1]]
```